# Youtube - Full screen is unavailable

Tags: youtube, fullscreen

The problem is that I can not play YouTube movies in fullscreen. I am getting the following error: "*Full screen is unavailable*" (https://gyazo.com/159b3f51db4bb643e6ef10854b18ddd0, see screenshot)

I've tried it in multiple browsers and only one of them is working:

- Internet Explorer 10 (versie 10.0.9200.16921) **WORKING**

The rest of the internet browsers is not working:

- Internet Explorer 11 (versie 11.306.10586.0) **NOT WORKING**
- Firefox (versie 46.0.1) **NOT WORKING**
- Google Chrome (versie 50.0.2661.102 m **NOT WORKING**
- Google Chrome (versie 30.0.1700.102 m **NOT WORKING**

Why is it working in an older Internet Explorer and all new browsers are not?

Also "*allowfullscreen*" is getting removed when I save in my editor and parameters like "*allowfullscreen="true"*" are also not working.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Gl7ABg9lnBM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I really don't know what is causing the problem so I hope you guys can help me out!

Comment: I had the same issue, just ran `killall firefox` in the terminal and started it again, now it works. Weird.

Answer (score 16):

this worked for me, because we are using React, so not sure if this helps: simply change allowfullscreen to allowFullScreen with uppercase "F" and "S". now works in all browsers.